# Removing Hyperlink from Powerpoint notes using C# interop?

Tags: c#, office-interop

Is there a way to remove hyperlinks from the PowerPoint slide notes page/notes?

Please share the interop code snippet implemented in C#.

Comment: What research have you done so far? What have you tried? what was the result?

Comment: A google search brings up multiple results. What's wrong with the existing articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Slide.NotesPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.notespage) property which returns a `SlideRange` object that represents the notes pages for the specified slide or range of slides.

The `NotesPage` property returns the notes page for either a single slide or a range of slides and allows you to make changes only to those notes pages. If you want to make changes that affect all notes pages, use the `NotesMaster` property to return the Slide object that represents the notes master.